# Convert VB's Format() into PHP

Tags: php, com, excel, vba

In PHP, I'm trying to read an Excel file using COM():

```
$rrc_app = new COM("Excel.application");
$rrc_workbook = $rrc_app->Workbooks->Open($filename);
$rrc_worksheet = $rrc_workbook->Worksheets('Top sheet');
$rrc_worksheet->activate;
```

I tried to extract the value of a cell containing a "Time" value:

```
$review_time = $rrc_worksheet->Range("C30")->value;
```

However, it returns a decimal number:

```
0.604166666667
```

I know I can use the Format() function of VB, but I don't know from what object in PHP to call it from. The following:

```
$review_time = Format($rrc_worksheet->Range("C30")->value, "hh:mm:ss");
```

Gives:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function Format() in C:\xampplite\htdocs\pmc\index.php on line 40
```

Do you happen to know how I can call this Format() function using PHP?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As a side note: The decimal number is just "the fraction of the day represented by that time value", so it should not be difficult to convert this value manually (multiply with 24 to get the hours, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Format` is a function of the `VBA.String` module, so it's not part of the Excel COM library and I'm not sure if it is accessible via COM at all.

However, you can use the `Text` property instead of `Value`: This returns a formatted string (according to the cell format in Excel) rather than the underlying value:

```
$review_time = $rrc_worksheet->Range("C30")->Text;
```

---

EDIT: If the cell does not have the correct format yet, you can change the format before reading the `Text` property (untested):

```
$rrc_worksheet->Range("C30")->Select();
$rrc_app->Selection->NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss";
$review_time = $rrc_worksheet->Range("C30")->Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

Format() looks like a [Visual Basic function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wb216dct%28VS.71%29.aspx). It is not necessarily available to you throught the Excel COM object you are communicating with - only if that object declares it somewhere. The VB function range is not imported automatically into PHP when talking to a COM object.

Can you try `$rrc_app->Format()`?

If nothing works, I recommend figuring out what the time value stands for (I'm sure you can find out here on SO) and converting it in PHP.